# Best approach for real time process information / Server + JS Client

Tags: extjs, asp.net-web-api, extjs4, signalr, real-time

I have a `C# Web API` project on server side and on front-end I have `ExtJS` 4.2.1 (Javascript framework client).

There is a section in my app where I request to start a long running process (about 5 minutes) and I want to show the user the status of the process being executed.

> > Basically, the process will run a special calculation for every employee in the database (about 800), so I want to let the user know which **Employee** is being processed in that moment.

So I was thinking in two ways of doing this, and maybe I don't know if having both is ok.

1. Use `SignalR` to show the information of the process in Real Time.
2. Write to a `database table` all the process log (every employee that its being processed).

> If I use the first approach, if the user close the browser he will loose all the information about the process and if he log into the app again he will only see the actual status.
>
> If I use the second approach, if he log into the app again he could see all the information, and using maybe a timer on client side the data could be refreshed every 5 seconds.

Does anyone have implemented something like this? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a combination of the two. When you have calculated a employee save the state to the database and publish the change on a service bus.

Let SignalR pick these messages up and forward them to the client. This way the user will see old state when he connects and new state then they arrive with SignalR. I have created a Event aggregator proxy that makes this very easy.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Follow the wiki to set it up, here is a demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Live demo
http://malmgrens.org/Signalr/